# Linux Slackware 14.2 pinging doesn't work

Tags: networking, slackware

I'm new in Linux Slackware. I recently installed `Linux Slackware 14.2` (in VMWare) with no interface. I tried to do `ping 8.8.8.8` but it fails, in fact no message comes out, it stays as shown below. I have tried to configure the network with `netconfig`, but am facing the same problem.

```
root@david:~# ifconfig
lo: flags=73<UP,L00PBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host> 
        loop txqueuelen 1 (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 78 bytes 6552 (6.3 Kig)
        RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 
        TX packets 78 bytes 6552 (6.3 Kig)
        TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

root@david:~# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

What am I doing wrong?

The output of `lspci`

```
00:16.1 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:16.2 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:16.3 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:16.4 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:16.5 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:16.6 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:16.7 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.0 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.1 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.2 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.3 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.4 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.5 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.6 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:17.7 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.0 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.1 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.2 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.3 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.4 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.5 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.6 Class 0604: Device 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
00:18.7 Class 0604: DevIce 15ad:07a0 (rev 01)
02:00.0 Class 0200: Device 8086:100f (rev 01)
```

Comment: What Ethernet controllers do you find in the output from `lspci`?  Please include it in your question.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already added it Oskar.

Comment: It appears lspci has different defaults on Slackware, but some Googling tells me that 8086:100f is an "Intel 82545EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller" which shouldn't be a problem.  What do you get if you run `lsmod | grep e1000`?

Comment: does not print anything. i'm sorry i forget to say that it is being installed in VMWare.

Comment: Could you please stop using a distro **meant for Linux pros** and use something a little bit popular and modern, e.g. Fedora 32 or Ubuntu 20.10. The interface you've "configured" is loopback. It won't get you anywhere. Also your `lspci` output is broken because you're missing hardware database - you must have forgotten to install it because and Slackware doesn't have dependencies tracking to do that automatically.

Comment: I installed it with packages A and N on the following page: https://www.slackwiki.com/Minimal_System#, the idea of this was to install linux with the least possible weight (approximately 1GB)

Answer (score 0):

"recently i install linux slackware 14.2(in VMWare) no interface" ...meaning no network interface? You need to add a (virtual) network adapter to your VM, with VMware defaulting to "VMXNET 3" type. If using SR-IOV just select the VF you want.